# everything works independitly but not together. Piezo not generating a tone

Tags: arduino-uno, piezo, buzzer

My goal with the code is simple. Let the Piezo buzz when temperature reaches 25 degrees. My piezo is hooked up correctly, because It makes a buzz when the arduino boots or when I put this line of code anywhere else in my code.

I also checked if the If statement was called. And yes it is! So the if statements is happening yet I don't hear a buzz.

I am aware that I am breaking my seven segmented screen by using the delay. But I don't mind the screen working when the buzzer is.

```
void loop()
{
  //local vars
  if (millis() % 5000 <= 10) {
      float lm35TempC = lm35.getTempC();
      sevseg.setNumber(lm35TempC, 2);
      if (lm35TempC > 25.00) {
        tone(1,500,1000);
        delay(3000);  <------- WHERE IT PROBABLY GOES WRONG
      }
      if (lm35TempC < 25.00) {
        noTone(1);
      }
  }
  sevseg.refreshDisplay(); // Must run repeatedly; don't use blocking code (ex: delay()) in the loop() function or this won't work right
}
```

To conclude: The If-statement is working yet I don't hear a buzz. How does this happen?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The windows of `millis() % 5000 <= 10` is only 10ms every 5 second. How long does the function `sevseg.refreshDisplay` take? more than 10ms?

Comment: No I dont think that function will take much longer, but I have to admit its a ugly way of creating a delay of 5 seconds, but if I for example increase 10 to 50, my display will sometimes refresh twice within a short timeframe

Comment: Then stop doing it in a ugly way. Use https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay with an interval of 5 seconds. After that you have to fix the tone, I think that is ugly as well. A tone with duration will delay and does not need noTone. There might be hardware problems as well. Fix everything one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You connected the piezo to pin 1? Chose other pin. Pin 1 is Serial TX. You 'pump' PWM to USB.

tone() function will make sound no matter if you have a delay there. You set 1 sec with 1000 as third parameter. It will sound 1 sec and the turn of. **You do not need the delay() and noTone()**.

500 is low frequency. If it sounds only one second, can you catch it?

try `tone(TONE_PIN, 4500, 500)`. with speaker it is a nice beeeep

Comment: You were right! The only reason I used pin 1 was, that I allready used all the other Digital Pins (expect 0 but that one is like 1). I have now configured an Analog Pin as output and it works Perfectly!